# Error getting value from 'ServerVersion' when trying to JsonConvert.SerializeObject

Tags: c#, .net, json, entity-framework, model-view-controller

I have a very basic code using Entity Framework to get a model in my MVC C# .NET Controller.

```
var myModel = myContext.MyData
                .Where(m => m.ID == 1)
                .FirstOrDefault();

string json = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(myModel);
```

When I try to run this code, I get an error:

Error getting value from `ServerVersion` on `System.Data.SqlClient`.

... If I press `Continue`, the view says:

> [InvalidOperationException: Invalid operation. The connection is
>   closed.]

What's wrong? What does SQL have to do with this? The same error comes if I do this in the View instead of the Controller.

**Edit:**

My class (model)

```
namespace TrackerEntityFrameworks.Models
{
  public class MyData: DbContext
  {
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public DateTime StartTime { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public DateTime EndTime { get; set; }

    public ICollection<TripRecord> TripRecords { get; set; }
    public ICollection<TollRecord> TollRecords { get; set; }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're Trying to serialize the entire `Dbcontext`, don't do that!

Remove the inheritance of `MyData` from `DbContext` and you should be fine.

Your business class must be "persistance ignorant", in order to be reusable and Entity Framework works perfectly in this way

Comment: It is only the line with the Json serialization that messes up. If I pass my model to the View, I can access it as normally. But I want it as Json.

Comment: Can you share your `MyData` class?

Comment: You're trying to serialize the entire `dbcontext`, don't do that! Remove the inheritance of `MyData` from `DbContext`

Comment: Ohh.. Now this all makes more sense! But the guide I followed wanted me to write it this way, although it seems it works without too - for now. Will I get trouble later? PS: Edit your answer, and Ill make it the right one - thanks a lot :)

Comment: Done. With this change you'll never have problems, it's the right way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Seperate the DbContext from your entity then do the following:

```
namespace TrackerEntityFrameworks.Structure
{
  public class MyContext: DbContext
  {
    public DbSet<TripRecord> TripRecords { get; set; }
    public DbSet<TollRecord> TollRecords { get; set; }
    public DbSet<MyData> MyDatas { get; set; }
  }
}

namespace TrackerEntityFrameworks.Models
{
  public class MyData
  {
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public DateTime StartTime { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public DateTime EndTime { get; set; }

    // navigation properties: check how to implement relationships in EF Code First
    public ICollection<TripRecord> TripRecords { get; set; }
    public ICollection<TollRecord> TollRecords { get; set; }
  }
}


using(var myContext = new TrackerEntityFrameworks.Structure.MyContext())
{
  var result = myContext.MyDatas
                  .Where(m => m.ID == 1)
                  .FirstOrDefault();
  string json = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(result);
}
```

Entity framework tutorial: http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/entity-framework-code-first.aspx